# macOS Mojave Shutdown cause

Tags: macos, mojave, shutdown, reboot

I am working on macOS Mojave unified logs,which are as follows:

```
2019-04-29 11:16:07.480418+0900 0xc2       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2019-04-29 11:16:16.029045+0900 0x708      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOPlatformPluginFamily)    Shutdown cause was a PWROK event (Same as GEN_PMCON_2 bit 0)
2019-04-29 11:16:16.029046+0900 0x708      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOPlatformPluginFamily)    Shutdown cause was a PWROK event (Same as GEN_PMCON_2 bit 0)
2019-04-29 11:16:16.029048+0900 0x708      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOPlatformPluginFamily)    Shutdown cause was a SYS_PWROK event (Same as GEN_PMCON_2 bit 1)
2019-04-29 11:16:16.029049+0900 0x708      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOPlatformPluginFamily)    Shutdown cause was a SYS_PWROK event (Same as GEN_PMCON_2 bit 1)
2019-04-29 11:16:16.029051+0900 0x708      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOPlatformPluginFamily)    Shutdown cause was a THRMTRIP# event (Same as GEN_PMCON_2 bit 3)
2019-04-29 11:16:16.029051+0900 0x708      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOPlatformPluginFamily)    Shutdown cause was a THRMTRIP# event (Same as GEN_PMCON_2 bit 3)
2019-04-29 11:31:33.524822+0900 0xc2       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 1
2019-04-29 11:31:42.320623+0900 0x71f      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOPlatformPluginFamily)    Shutdown cause was a PWROK event (Same as GEN_PMCON_2 bit 0)
2019-04-29 11:31:42.320623+0900 0x71f      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOPlatformPluginFamily)    Shutdown cause was a PWROK event (Same as GEN_PMCON_2 bit 0)
2019-04-29 11:31:42.320625+0900 0x71f      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOPlatformPluginFamily)    Shutdown cause was a SYS_PWROK event (Same as GEN_PMCON_2 bit 1)
2019-04-29 11:31:42.320626+0900 0x71f      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOPlatformPluginFamily)    Shutdown cause was a SYS_PWROK event (Same as GEN_PMCON_2 bit 1)
2019-04-29 11:31:42.320628+0900 0x71f      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOPlatformPluginFamily)    Shutdown cause was a THRMTRIP# event (Same as GEN_PMCON_2 bit 3)
2019-04-29 11:31:42.320629+0900 0x71f      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOPlatformPluginFamily)    Shutdown cause was a THRMTRIP# event (Same as GEN_PMCON_2 bit 3)
```

What do the following mean:

1. Previous shutdown cause: 5 (Previous shutdown cause on High Sierra means normal shutdown). Can it be the same in Mojave?
2. "Shutdown cause was a PWROK event" (Same as GEN_PMCON_2 bit 0)
3. "Shutdown cause was a THRMTRIP# event"

Comments/observations are welcome

Comment: I have the very same issue. Pls, whow can I reach the unified logs ?. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a shutdown cause value of 5 means it was a totally normal shutdown.

A *"Shutdown cause was a PWROK event"* basically means that your system shutdown with no power supply issues - as in PWROK = Power Okay.

A *"Shutdown cause was a THRMTRIP# event"* basically means that your system shutdown due to a thermal trip - most likely due to overheating - so your Mac shuts down to protect itself from damage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same logs on macbook pro 13" 2018 i7 macOS 10.14.5. I leave my machine in my backpack at the end of the day and every morning when I boot up it's starting from a recent shutdown.

I can’t prove this technically,  but my thinking is that it wakes from sleep while in my bag and then overheats.

- this started after updating to 10.14.5
- power nap could allow it to wake
- so could physical jostling

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You’ve posted this as an answer, which is only for things that directly answer the question asked. I’m going to turn it into an answer by editing it, please self delete his post if you’re not ok with that refinement and positive statement

Comment: @mat.The unified logs in High Sierra for shutdown have a different syntax  as in "shutdown cause: 5".